# Core Data binding to NSTableView automatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

Just wondering if there is a binding that can be set from an NSTableView to an Array Controller that is setup to read from Core Data that will automatically label all the columns and populate the table.

I can bind individual columns no problem but was just wondering if there was a faster way that didn't involve manually labelling the columns.

Thanks for your help, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Table views don't generate columns automatically.

You could implement a table view subclass that did this, by processing the entity description and creating and binding the columns.

You'd encounter these design questions:

- What order to print the columns (is alphabetical what you want?)
- How to display relationships, especially to-many relationships